# Doubly linked lists in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, doubly-linked-list

I'm working on a project where I manipulate a lot of sorted lists of elements, and I need to be able to remove any of these quickly. Since I don't need any kind of indexation, I thought that the doubly linked list structure would be best. I couldn't find any good pre-made module so I made my own:

```
class Node: # nodes for doubly-linked lists
    def __init__(self, val, dll):
        self.val = val
        self.next = None
        self.prev = None
        self.dll = dll

class DLList: # doubly-linked lists
    def __init__(self):
        self.first = None
        self.last = None
        self.len = 0

#    def __iter__(self):
#        self.curr = self.first
#        return self
#    
#    def __next__(self):
#        if self.curr == None:
#            raise StopIteration
#        self.curr = self.curr.next
#        if self.curr == None:
#            raise StopIteration
#        return self.curr

    def append(self, val): # add a node with value val at the end of the list
        node = Node(val, self)
        node.prev = self.last
        self.last = node
        if self.first == None: # <=> if self was empty
            self.first = node
        self.len += 1

    def appendleft(self, val): # same as previous, but at the beginning of the list
        node = Node(val, self)
        node.next = self.first
        self.first = node
        if self.last == None:
            self.last = node
        self.len += 1

    def nodeat(self, i): # gives the ith node (starting at 0)
        if i == -1:
            return None
        if i > self.len or i < -1:
            raise IndexError('index out of range')
        curr = self.first
        for j in range(i):
            curr = curr.next
        return curr

    def remove(self, node): # remove a given node in the list
        if node.dll != self: #cannot remove a node that is not in the list
            raise ValueError('node not in list')
        p = node.prev
        n = node.next
        v = node.val
        node.dll = None
        if p != None:
            p.next = n
        else:
            self.first = n
        if n != None:
            n.prev = p
        else:
            self.last = p
        self.len -= 1
        return v

    def add(self, val, i): # add a node at the ith place in the list
        node = Node(val, self)
        if i > self.len:
            raise IndexError('index out of range')
        self.len += 1
        previ = self.nodeat(i)
        node.prev = previ.prev
        node.next = previ
        previ.prev = node

    def clear(self): # empty the list
        self.first = None
        self.last = None
        self.len = 0

    def extend(self, iterable): # add the elements of iterable in order at the end of the list
        for i in iterable:
            self.append(i)
            self.len += 1

    def extendleft(self, iterable): # same as previous, but at the beginning (and in reverse order)
        for i in iterable:
            self.appendleft(i)
            self.len += 1

    def dll_to_list(self): # return a python list with the elements of the doubly-linked list
        res = []
        curr = self.first
        while curr != None:
            res.append(curr.val)
            curr = curr.next
        return res

    def is_empty(self): # check whether the list is empty
        return self.len == 0
```

Since I would lose time checking that the item I want to remove is in the list by browsing it, I added a pointer toward the list a Node is in inside the node, so that I can check that I'm not removing things from the wrong list.

Those lists are stocked in a Python dictionary, and at some point I started getting 'node not in list' errors. Does anyone know how it could appear? I never use anything but the methods listed here to manipulate the lists...

Otherwise, does anyone know about a well-coded module that I could use in place of this one?

Thanks!

Comment: Without seeing the code that's trying to do the removals, I don't think we can possibly guess why you're getting the error you describe. The code you have shown would raise that error if you tried to remove the same node twice, so I'd guess you're doing that somehow. I'd also note that it is very unusual to have a container like a list serve as its own iterator (usually containers are only iterable, not iterators themselves).

Comment: Yeah, it's for work so I'm not comfortable putting the complete code up here, but you make a good point. For the iterator, it didn't work so I scrapped it and I forgot to remove this bit of code... I'll learn how to do it properly another time!

Answer (score 3):

A doubly linked list has links going both directions.

Example:

```
def append(self, val): # add a node with value val at the end of the list
    node = Node(val, self)  # new node, ok
    node.prev = self.last   # ok, the new nodes prev is the last node of your list
    self.last = node        # ok, your new node is now the last of your list 
    if self.first == None:  # yeah, ok, if its empty its also the first one now
        self.first = node
    self.len += 1
```

but ... you do not set the back-direction:

```
    node.prev.next = node  # before  node.prev = self.last
```

Similar in your other appends. You have to always clear/reset/set all the links in *both* directions if you add/remove things into a doubly-linked-list:

[image: append-drawing]

( Red are all the changed variabels on append )

Essentially your list is not complete - if you operate / iterate on it, things will go missing in unexpected ways

Comment: That's... incredibly stupid and I can't believe it didn't come up sooner! I'm not sure it caused my issue because the error message was very specific, but I'm sure glad you caught that one... It does explain some other weird things that I have noticed, though. Thank you very much!

Comment: Not quite sure what warrented the downvote ... on a post that this old. If you have feedback how to better the answer quality, procide feedback. Thanks.